# Add a service reference that is hosted in a private VPN to my project

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-5, vpn

**Requirement:** Add a service reference that is hosted in a private VPN to my project.

**IDE** Visual Studio 2013 express edition

**Language** C#

**Framework** MVC 5

**Question:**

1. While adding the service reference, where do I specify the credentials to join the VPN?
2. Should the owners of that VPN whitelist my Ip?
3. How do we add a service reference that is hosted in a VPN to my Visual Studio MVC.

**What I did:**

1. I tried to add the reference by doing the following:

   Right clicking on the service reference folder.
            click Add Service Reference.
            Enter URL 
            Click Go   (Did not work)
2. I also went through several msdn and stackoverflow articles and couldnot find anything comprehensible.

**Failure messages:**

The remote name could not be resolved.

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved.

There was no endpoint listening at  that can accept the message.

**Note:** Thanks in advance for helping me out with this. I am new to this and not sure if I am looking in the right places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create service reference, VS2013 will take the WSDL and generate the stack which is used to call the service. So VS2013 will call the service and it needs access to it.
VPN is a security layer down to http layer so it is not possible to put credential in http layer. You need to give VPN to your computer with some VPN client first and it'll work.

Comment: Hmm let me check on that and will accept as correct answer if it works. Thank you

Comment: I am using Cisco AnyConnect VPN and am able to browse to the WSDL definition when logged into the VPN client, however I'm still not able to create a service reference to this same URL from VS 2017. I enter the URL and it just sits there and spins until I cancel out of it.